# Delete query generating UncategorizedSQLException and ORACLE memory issue in SPRING framework

Tags: java, spring, oracle, exception, jdbctemplate

I am trying to process a delete query in eclipse using the SPRING jdbcTemplate and ORACLE as DBMS.
The code is the following :

```
jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE FROM PRMSVC_EF WHERE EF_SSC_ID in (SELECT es.EF_SSC_ID FROM EF_SSC es WHERE es.NUMCPTPFS = '1086878547'")
```

as error I get

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException : StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for [DELETE FROM PRMSVC_EF WHERE EF_SSC_ID in (SELECT es.EF_SSC_ID FROM EF_SSC es WHERE es.NUMCPTPFS = '1086878547']
```

and also the following oracle error :

```
ORA-12853 : ORA-12853: insufficient memory for PX buffers
```

When I process the query in oracle DBMS it takes 2 secs to execute. I am trying to find a sollution for the java code itself rather than trying to extend the SGA pools memory or something ...
Any Ideas ?

Comment: `alter table PRMSVC_EF noparallel;`

Comment: does this disables the parallelism in my queries ?

Comment: yes. if is better practice to enable it on session or statement level. than on object level.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

alter system set parallel_max_servers=50 scope=both sid='*';

see here : 
http://zaakeroracledba.blogspot.ca/2015/03/ora-12853-insufficient-memory-for-px.html

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2400781?tstart=0