# PL/SQL Convert to JSON

Tags: json, database, loops, plsql, database-cursor

I'm new to using PL/SQL (although I have some SQL experience before). I have been trying to convert a particular data into JSON. I did research throughout the Internet but I couldn't figure out what was wrong on my code. It did produced errors such as "ORA-12801". This is actually a large dataset that I'm working on. I would like to use only the cursor loop as it is because it is much easier to use than using other libraries. Therefore, could you offer an opinion or thought after looking through the code? 
**UPDATE: I'm using Toad for Oracle for the data.
**UPDATE2: I have already looked into the other link and that didn't solve my problem because I do not wish to use other libraries such as PL/JSON. Rather, I would like to use a simple cursor statement in PL/SQL to convert the table's columns into JSON only.

```
DECLARE 
  links varchar2(750);

  CURSOR statement
  IS
    SELECT DISTINCT NAME, GROUP
    FROM ST.PEOPLE
    GROUP BY ST.PEOPLE.NAME, ST.PEOPLE.GROUP
    ORDER BY ST.PEOPLE.NAME ASC;

BEGIN 
  FOR line IN statement
  LOOP
    links := '{"source":"'|| line.NAME ||'", "target":"'|| line.GROUP||'""}';
  END LOOP;

  dbms_output.put_line(links);

END;
```

Fails with:

```
ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P045
ORA-12853: insufficient memory for PX buffers: current 16352K, max needed 702720K
ORA-04031: unable to allocate 65560 bytes of shared memory (“large pool”, “unknown object”, “large pool”, “PX msg pool”)
ORA-06512: at line 17
```

[image: The error while running]

Comment: Does that query give the same error when run on its own on the command line? All I can think of is the `PEOPLE` table has some degree of parallelism defined, hence an ordinary cursor giving a PX error, and it has too much data to perform the `DISTINCT`/`ORDER BY` on those two keys. How many rows does it contain? Do you really need all of them? Does the code work with a smaller number of rows?

Comment: No, I have not tried running the query on the cmd line. The table has a large amount of rows. Currently, I'm trying to load the values from the "name" and "group" columns only. As of now, the code is actually a modified version of the original code. The original code had more columns about 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return results of a sql query as JSON in oracle 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560996/return-results-of-a-sql-query-as-json-in-oracle-12c)

Comment: I don't think the question has much to do with either JSON or PL/SQL, since the error seems to be related to the cursor alone and not any JSON-specific processing. Probably you could change the question to something like "Large GROUP BY with ORDER BY fails with ORA-12853: insufficient memory for PX buffers", and show only the query.

Comment: Searching for `ORA-12853`, the advice seems to be to `alter table people noparallel` or reduce the `parallel_max_servers` parameter setting. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36478807/230471

Comment: I tried to reduce the query in executing a simple query "select column1, column2 from table". Apparently, it didn't work.

Comment: I have found the answer to my own question. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using one of the database's buttons to turn on the output on the "DBMS Output" for executing the code and it worked.